# how to SPLIT and COUNT by GROUP BY

Tags: count, group-by, split

my current query is like this:

```
SELECT Discipline, COUNT(*) Cnt FROM [xxx].[dbo].[ScanDoc] 
WHERE Discipline <> ''
GROUP BY Discipline
```

the result is like this..

```
Discipline                                         Cnt
Advanced Material Science                           1
Advanced Material Science;#Chemical Science         2
Advanced Material Science;#Engineering Science      1
Agriculture Science                                 1
Business and Economics                              3
Computer Sciences and ICT                           1
Computer Sciences and ICT;#Business and Economics   1
Engineering Science                                 3
Health and Medical Science                          3
Health and Medical Science;#Life Science            2
Humanities and Social Science                       9
Life Science                                        1
```

so what i want is to split the multiple value..sifoo please show me the way..

i want result like this

```
Discipline                                         Cnt
Advanced Material Science                           4
Chemical Science                                     2
Engineering Science                                 1
Agriculture Science                                 1
Business and Economics                              3
Computer Sciences and ICT                           2
Business and Economics                              1
Engineering Science                                 3
Health and Medical Science                          5
Humanities and Social Science                       9
Life Science                                        3
```

do you see the different between the results?

Comment: What do you mean? Plese provide result example based on your data.

Comment: please refer the above question...i want to seperate the 'discipline' and count it...TQ

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no SPLIT function in SQL Server so your best bet would be to create a SPLIT function and then call it from a union query, first taking first part and the second taking the latter part of Discipline!